# Unit Testing for a random number

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I am trying to create a junit test on a random number generator. However, I am not sure how you do this.

```
package main;
import java.util.Random;
    
public class Dice {
    public int DiceRoll() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.nextInt(6)+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What characteristics of this class do you want your test to verify?

Comment: I just want to test that it returns a random number that is between 1-6 as it is a dice

Comment: Then you could call it multiple times until you verify its range of output.

Comment: Could you demonstrate it please I am very new to this

Comment: At the end it only tests the java random class.

Comment: BTW. Take care of java naming conventions. Method names should start with lowercase character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the Dice class like this:

```
public Dice {

    private Random random;

    public Dice(Random random) {
        this.random = random;
    }
}
```

Then in the test you can inject a mock, which can return a predefined value...